# How to convert value of type IQueryable<User> to Either<Error, IQueryable<User>>

Tags: c#, language-ext

Im using [Either](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/LanguageExt/Either_L_R.htm) in a function with the signature `public Either<Error, IQueryable<User>> Create(string userName)`, but when trying to return a result of type `IQueryable<User>` I get a conversion error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<User>` to `LanguageExt.Either<Error, System.Linq.IQueryable<User>>`

I am sure there is a way to construct a valid return type, I just don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

Found out it can be done with `Prelude.Right(result)`. Odd that its not mentioned on the Either docs.